# Select field for leaflet color dynamically from a character string

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

The question is probably not too hard, but I couldn't find the words to properly google it.

I'm building a function in R that makes a leaflet map.  The user will be able to chose the field he wants to use for colors in the form of a simple function argument `field_color = "AREA"` where `AREA` is the field name in the `sf` object.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)

# preparing the shapefile
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')

# setting the colors
colpal <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", domain=nc$AREA, n=10)

# making the first map like in your example:
leaflet(nc) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(color = ~colpal(AREA))
```

This code works and gives :

[image]

But in the preceding example, `AREA` is unquote.  If I want it an argument, I need to call it that way:

```
chosen_field = "AREA"

# setting the colors
colpal2 <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", domain=nc[[chosen_field]], n=10)

# making the first map like in your example:
leaflet(nc) %>%
   addTiles() %>%
   addPolygons(color = ~colpal2(chosen_field))
Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
  no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "character"
```

That way, I could set `chosen_field` to the value I want to automatically change the color.  However, it's not working and I get an error.  I have a feeling it's some king of problem with Non Standard Evaluation or something but I don't really understand all of that.  I played around function like  `quo`, `enquo`, `quo_name` etc. without success.

What is the proper way to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'd suggest just sidestepping the issue by "pre-computing" your color data outside of the pipe, just as you've already pre-computed your color palette. That may feel inelegant, but then I'd argue that the convolutions **magrittr** et al. are forcing you into here are at least as awkward. Additionally, the approach I'm suggesting is exactly that used by the "pros"  [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/063-superzip-example/server.R#L73-L96) in their production of [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html) example leaflet app.

Specifically, I'd use something like this:

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)

## User-selected parameter
chosen_field <- "AREA"

## Shapefile preparation
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')

## Color setup
colpal <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", domain=nc[[chosen_field]], n=10)
colorData <- nc[[chosen_field]]

## Putting it all together
leaflet(nc) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
    addPolygons(color = ~colpal(colorData))
```

Alternatively, if you **must** do it the "**rlang** way", here is another solution, modeled off of the discussion recorded [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/functional-programming-around-leaflet-with-nse/26477/6). See how much more unreadable this is, though?

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)

## User-selected parameter
chosen_field <- "AREA"

## Prep user-selected parameter for passage into pipe
v <- as.symbol(chosen_field)
v <- enquo(v)

## Shapefile preparation
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')

## Color setup
colpal <- colorNumeric(palette = "plasma", domain=nc[[chosen_field]], n=10)
colorData <- nc[[chosen_field]]

## Putting it all together
rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::quo_squash(quo({
    leaflet(nc) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
        addPolygons(color = ~colpal(!!v))
})))
```

Comment: nice complete answer, thanks.  I'll use the first way you propose, it's cleaner.

Comment: @Bastien Great. Glad that helped.